Is there any way to install qml language server for neovim in Linux?
I want to edit qml file in neovim, but can't find a way to install language server (qmlls) for it. Any body can help me resolve this problem? Thank you very much.
I serched qt website, nevom lsp config repo, etc. Can't find any clue.

It's a bit weird but you can't install only qmlls and need the whole QtDeclarative install. (i.e installing Qt >= 6.3.0 if you don't build from source)
Once you have it in PATH you just need to register to nvim-lsp, if you use nvim-lspconfig it's just:
require'lspconfig'.qmlls.setup{}

If you don't use lspconfig then check the server configuration on lspconfig and mimic what it does: qmlls server config

Thank you very much! I'll try it out.

The tools are available via their online installer. It's somewhere in the tools section.
If you are on a Linux distribution, you might want to consider installing Qt from the repositories tho.
In the Ubuntu repositories starting with 23.10:

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/23.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/qt6-declarative-dev-tools_6.4.2+dfsg-3_amd64.deb.html

In Fedora, it should be this package:

https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/qt6-qtdeclarative/qt6-qtdeclarative-devel


Thank you for answering. But this seems only works for editing in QtCreator.
